# sklearn LinearSVC - X has 1 features per sample; expecting 5

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to predict the class of a test array, but I'm getting the below error, along with the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/radu/PycharmProjects/Recommender/Temporary/classify_dict_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print classifier.predict(test)
  File "/home/radu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 215, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "/home/radu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 196, in decision_function
    % (X.shape[1], n_features))
ValueError: X has 1 features per sample; expecting 5
```

The code which is generating this is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

corpus = [
    "I am super good with Java and JEE",
    "I am super good with .NET and C#",
    "I am really good with Python and R",
    "I am really good with C++ and pointers"
    ]

classes = ["java developer", ".net developer", "data scientist", "C++ developer"]

test = ["I think I'm a good developer with really good understanding of .NET"]

tvect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=1)

X = tvect.fit_transform(corpus)

classifier = LinearSVC()
classifier.fit(X, classes)

print classifier.predict(test)
```

I've tried looking into the [LinearSVC documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC) for guidelines or hints as to what might throw this error, but I can't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The variable test is a string - the SVC needs a feature vector with the same number of dimensions as X. You have to transform the test string to a feature vector using the same vectorizer instance, before you feed it to the SVC:

```
X_test=tvect.transform(test)
classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Somehow I missed that, but it totally makes sense. Thank you!